# Is there a pandas function that can help me to turn a column values in new rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Input is a DF like this:

|  | Opened | short_description_tokens |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-04-15 | [falla, reloj, checador] |
| 1 | 2021-04-11 | [falla, outlet] |

Output should be a second data frame like this:

|  | Opened | stoken |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-04-15 | falla |
| 1 | 2021-04-15 | reloj |
| 2 | 2021-04-15 | checador |
| 3 | 2021-04-11 | falla |
| 4 | 2021-04-11 | outlet |

Thanks on the help :))

Comment: you just need `df.explode('short_description_tokens').rename(columns={'short_description_tokens':'stoken'})`